# Java Popup menu pops up multiple times after confirmation

Tags: java, popupmenu

I am trying to get a confirmation when the user presses the reset button to reset the high scores. When the user presses it, it asks if they are sure and then they confirm, once it has been confirmed it pops up again.

```
         rH.addActionListener((ActionEvent e) -> {

        int dialogButton5
                = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Are you sure you wish to reset leaderboard?", "Leaderboard", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

        if (dialogButton5 == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("");
            hScore = 0;
            Hname = " ";
            highScore.setText("High Score: " + hScore + " Name: " + Hname);

        } else if (dialogButton5 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: What's rH? I think we need more context

Comment: it is a jButton for reset high score

Comment: Post [mcve] that reproduces the problem. (By making one you are likely to find the problem yourself)